# SQLite3 foreign_key_check fails with error 1

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

I want to use `foreign_key_check` to check my SQLITE3 database using version 3.21.0.

The following statements applied to an empty table yield error 1 instead of a list of foreign key violations. The tables are clearly empty. Why do I get the error?

```
CREATE TABLE City(CityName TEXT NOT NULL, CityID INTEGER NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE Street(StreetName TEXT NOT NULL, CityID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES City(CityID));
PRAGMA foreign_key_check;
```

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes

Answer (score 0):

CityID is required to be UNIQUE.

In my usecase, the table City contains some cities with different variations of the name (New York == New York City) with the same CityID, hence it is not UNIQUE in my case. I need to change the database structure.

I still wonder why this is error 1. I can create the tables with `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` and no error.